# Makefile for assembly programs treats source files as target

Tags: assembly, makefile

I am new to **GNU make**. I would like to compile all my assembly source files into separate object files with the same names. In the future, if I add more assembly source files, the **Makefile** should still work without modification.

e.g. I am in root directory

```
$ ls
Makefile obj src
$ ls src
file1.s file2.s
```

After `make` I want

```
$ ls obj
file1.o file2.o
```

In the future if I add a `file3.s` to my `src` directory, after `make` I would like a new `file3.o` in my `obj` directory.

I've read about **static pattern rules** in the GNU make manual, and I think it is what I need. I have written the following Makefile:

```
path = /path/to/toolchain/bin
AS = $(path)/llvm-mc
ASFLAGS = -filetype=obj

srcdir = src
sources = $(srcdir)/*.s
objdir = obj
objects = $(objdir)/*.o

.PHONY: all
all: $(objects)

$(objects): $(objdir)/%.o: $(srcdir)/%.s
        $(AS) $(ASFLAGS) $< -o $@

.PHONY: clean
clean:
        rm $(objects)
```

After running `make` in shell, I got the error:

```
make: *** No rule to make target `src/*.s', needed by `obj/*.o'.  Stop.
```

Can anyone tell me what mistake I made? I have checked that I used tab in front of the recipe. Thank you in advance.

Comment: `sources = $(srcdir)/*.s` --> `sources = $(wildcard $(srcdir)/*.s)` ?  And likewise for `objects = $(objdir)/*.o` .

Comment: It's generally a good idea to avoid using wildcards in makefiles.  Explicitly listing the objet files makes for a much more predictable makefile.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This cannot work:

```
objects = $(objdir)/*.o
```

When you run make for the first time, what will this expand to?  You have no object files, so the wildcard will expand to no files.  Or if you have some object files and create a new source file what will it expand to?  It will expand only to the existing object files.

Since you're only asking make to build object files that already exist, it will never build ones that don't exist.

What you need to do is tell make to build an object file *for every source file*.

You can do that like this:

```
srcdir = src
sources = $(wildcard $(srcdir)/*.s)
objdir = obj
objects = $(sources:$(srcdir)/%.c=$(objdir)/%.o)
```